# Temporarily disable screen time restrictions

Tags: iphone, ios, screen-time

Is it possible to temporarily disable screen time restrictions? I have specific restrictions set for the weekdays and want to release them or have other set of restrictions then. Currently I can only turn off screen time but it resets all the configurations I've made already and the next time I want to set them again, I need to start from beginning.

Can I save these restrictions somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can't switch users on an iPad either like you do on a computer. I guess it is a way of forcing us to buy separate devices for each adult and child in the household.